# MySQL backup command not working

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, backup, mysql-backup

I'm trying to take a backup of a MySQL database using the following command:

```
mysql -u "username" -p "databasename" > "somename.sql"
```

After I enter the password, it doesn't show any output/error. It doesn't show the terminal prompt. No backup file gets created.

I've used the same command successfully before. But I have no clue why it isn't working now.
Any ideas?

I work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: `mysql` is the interface to mysql. you want `mysqldump`, which is the backup tool. what you're doing is basically pointless. firing up the mysql shell, and then it sits there waiting for input which never comes.

Comment: Marc B is right; but you will use mysql ... < "somename.sql" if you ever need to recreate your database from this backup. It is a little confusing. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying wrong command

```
mysqldump -u "username" -p"password" "databasename" > "somename.sql"
```

or it

```
 mysqldump -u "username" -p "databasename" > "somename.sql"
```

and type password when prompt.

Answer (score 0):

mysql -u "username" -p "databasename" > "somename.sql"

your username should be root

```
Log in to root account
then stop database server
and 
Try this code
```

mysqldump -u root -p dbname > backup.db.sql

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this command:**

**SYNTAX:**

```
mysqldump -u root -p -h MYSQL_MACHIE_IP --routines DATABASE_NAME | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' > BACKUP_FILE_NAME.sql
```

**EX:**

```
mysqldump -u root -p -h 12.123.11.123 --routines my_day_out | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' > backup_15thjuly_with_sp.sql
```

The above command will generate a .sql file with **Stored Procedures backup queries.**